# How should I use a 'continue' command to avoid an infinite loop in python?

Tags: python, while-loop, infinite-loop, continue

I am trying to get the program to accept an age value, print a response of ticket price,  and then return back to the prompt for input to request another age.

Every time I enter an age input I get an infinite loop? How can I approach it differently? Will a **continue** help?

Apologies for the sloppy formatting etc; it's my first post on stack overflow and I

```
ticket_age = input("\nTell me your age and I will sell you a ticket")


active = True
while active:
    age = int(ticket_age)

    if age < 3:
        print("You get a free ticket")


    elif age >= 3 and age <= 12:
        print("That will be $10 please")

    elif age > 12:
        print("That will be $15 please")
```

Comment: What is your question? What do you want to achieve?

Comment: Please add some text explanation alongside your code, to explain what you're trting to do.

Comment: the 'continue' command inside a loop continues to the next iteration of the loop; therefore, it will not break an infinite loop. You're looking for, for example, the "break" command.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How does break work in a for loop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45425259/how-does-break-work-in-a-for-loop)

Comment: I have update the above to try explain. Apologies for the lack of information at the start. It's my first post and I made a mistake when formatting the question.

Comment: @Ingwar 's answer works. Please take a look and accept it if it works for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use input inside of loop to perform that

```
while True:
    ticket_age = input("\nTell me your age and I will sell you a ticket")
    age = int(ticket_age)

    if age < 3:
        print("You get a free ticket")


    elif age >= 3 and age <= 12:
        print("That will be $10 please")

    elif age > 12:
        print("That will be $15 please")
```

Answer (score 0):

In your program, you should change the value of `active` variable to `false` somewhere inside your `while` loop to break it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this below :

```
ticket_age = input("\nTell me your age and I will sell you a ticket")


active = True
while active:
    age = int(ticket_age)

    if age < 3:
        print("You get a free ticket")


    elif age >= 3 and age <= 12:
        print("That will be $10 please")

    elif age > 12:
        print("That will be $15 please")

    else:
        break
```

Answer (score 0):

Welcome! As the comments said, we need more information on what you're tying to do. If it's just a simple check, then you don't even need the while loop. You could just have the if statements alone, or if you want to loop you could loop through multiple inputs. In your case you can exit by setting the active value to false. Otherwise, as a few pointers: in such loops you're using, you do not have to set `active = True` and then `while active:`, you can simply do `while True:`. But you will have to exit it somehow different. You can also directly convert input after receiving it, such as `ticket_age = int(input("\nTell me your age and I will sell you a ticket"))`, or `str(input(..))`. For your second loop, you can use such syntax: `if 3 <= number <= 12:`.

Comment: Hi Andre. Thanks for your help. I have edited my post above to try add some explanation to what I am trying to do.

Comment: You're welcome! It's pretty similar to the chosen one, but if you use "0" as a response, you'll get out of the loop yourself. You can mention it in your input string, or set some other number(s) as criteria that will take you out of the loop:


`while True:
    ticket_age = int(input("\nTell me your age and I will sell you a ticket:\n"))
    if ticket_age == 0:
        break
    elif ticket_age < 3:
        print("You get a free ticket!")
    elif 3 <= ticket_age <= 12:
        print("That will be $10, please.")
    elif ticket_age > 12:
        print("That will be $15, please.")`

Comment: Formatting seems to be broken in comments, the main point is that it has another if statement, with a `break` inside.