# Python : How to stop while loop while sorting list?

Tags: python, list, sorting, data-structures

I am writing code to sort elements in list and I kind of achieved it but unable to stop while loop.

I want to stop while loop when all element in list are sorted.

Code:

```
a = [27,21,22,1,11,23,0]
n=len(a)
while True:
    for i in range(n-1):
        if a[i]>a[i+1]:
            temp = a[i]
            a[i] = a[i+1]
            a[i+1] = temp
    print(a)
```

Output:

> [21, 22, 1, 11, 23, 0, 27] [21, 1, 11, 22, 0, 23, 27] [1, 11, 21, 0,
> 22, 23, 27] [1, 11, 0, 21, 22, 23, 27] [1, 0, 11, 21, 22, 23, 27] [0,
> 1, 11, 21, 22, 23, 27] [0, 1, 11, 21, 22, 23, 27] [0, 1, 11, 21, 22,
> 23, 27] [0, 1, 11, 21, 22, 23, 27]........

I know there are 10s of Q&A on sorting list but I want to achieve this way only(if possible).

Can anyone help me to stop this while loop?

Comment: You stop when `a[i] > a[i+1]` was never true for any `i`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How does break work in a for loop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45425259/how-does-break-work-in-a-for-loop)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps a bit more efficient than chepner's, not having an extra assignment for every swap, instead just use `temp` to detect whether there was a change:

```
a = [27,21,22,1,11,23,0]
n = len(a)
dummy = object()
while True:
    temp = dummy
    for i in range(n-1):
        if a[i]>a[i+1]:
            temp = a[i]
            a[i] = a[i+1]
            a[i+1] = temp
    if temp is dummy:
        break
    print(a)
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not just:

```
a = sorted(a)
```

Well, if you want to do that way:

```
a = [27,21,22,1,11,23,0]; a_bis = []
n=len(a)
while a_bis != a:
    a_bis = a.copy()
    for i in range(n-1):
        if a[i]>a[i+1]:
            temp = a[i]
            a[i] = a[i+1]
            a[i+1] = temp
    
    print(a)
```

Basically once there is a_bis = a it means nothing was sorted in the previous loop, so a must be sorted and you can exit

Answer (score 1):

You have to keep track of whether `a[i] > a[i+1]` was ever true. If not, your list is sorted, and you can break out of the loop.

```
a = [27,21,22,1,11,23,0]
n = len(a)
while True:
    stop = True
    for i in range(n-1):
        if a[i]>a[i+1]:
            stop = False
            # a[i], a[i+1] = a[i+1], a[i]
            temp = a[i]
            a[i] = a[i+1]
            a[i+1] = temp
    if stop:
        break
```

Comment: Just being curious, any difference between your way and mine below? You are certainly what to use in case of huge lists for memory issues, don't see apart from that

Comment: Effectively, my `stop` variable is the "anticipated" result of your list comparison. Instead of  actually making that comparison, I "predict" that it will fail by noting that any swap will *make* it fail.